# Connect two subnetworks through a third

Tags: linux, networking, git

I have a Linux desktop connecting to a remote site. When remoting in, this client is assigned to the 10.10.9 network. There is a gitlab server on the 10.10.11 network. 10.10.9 cannot access 10.10.11 directly. However, 10.10.9 can access 10.10.10, and 10.10.10 has access to all networks.

How can I make git on my 10.10.9 network connect to gitlab on the 10.10.11 network? I was assuming I would have to go through my Linux desktop on the 10.10.10 network somehow, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Are you an administrator of the remote site? When you remote in, are you doing it via a vpn tunnel?  If not, please describe how you are remoting into the remote site.

Comment: It is a VPN, yes.

Comment: Are you an administrator of the remote site?

Comment: Yes, but the config can't change.

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to add a route for the vpn subnet to be able to access the 10.10.11.0/24(?) subnet.

Comment: I was mainly wondering if there was a way to connect to my Linux box on the 10.10.10 network so that it could simply forward my request on to the gitlab server on the 10.10.11 network. So my box on 10.10.10 would essentially just be a passthrough.

Comment: I failed to see how `10.10.10.0/24`(?) is related to the other two subnets (other than "digitally"). `However, 10.10.9 can access 10.10.10, and 10.10.10 has access to all networks.` almost makes no sense. I mean, what are the routes and IPs on this `Linux desktop`? How many VPN have you connected it to? What's the topology here? Is it like one VPN server connecting all these subnets or what?

Comment: It also sounds absurd when you say you are the administrator and `10.10.9 cannot access 10.10.11 directly` but you want to override it (and you are not allowed to override it?).

Comment: I don't know how much clearer I can make this. The network is divided into many smaller networks. Some of these networks cannot physically access each other. If your computer is on the 10.10.9 network, there is no physical access, there's no route, to get to 10.10.11. However, there IS a route to 10.10.10, which then has a route to 10.10.11. These are physical properties, this is how someone designed the network at a hardware level. There is physically no link between some networks, but there is to others.

Comment: So all I'm trying to do is find a way to basically get from 10.10.9 to 10.10.11 using a computer on 10.10.10 as a passthrough. I've read this can be accomplished through ssh with -L, but I'm not clear on the details. There should be a way to, for example, run `git fetch` on the 10.10.9 network, and it goes through my passthrough on 10.10.10, which then forwards it to the gitlab server on 10.10.11 with gitlab none the wiser that it's coming from 10.10.9.

Comment: The routes are the routes.  Regardless of the protocols that get routed by the routes.  You can try all the various protocols you wish but underneath all that, you still have to have a route that get's the protocol to it's destination.